# Auto-fill Django OneToOneField

Tags: python, django, forms

This maybe a simple question, but I do not have any idea how to do this.
I have two models in Django.

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    some_member = models.Charfield(...)

class ModelB(models.Model):
    model = OneToOneField(ModelA)
    other_member = models.Charfield(...)
```

`ModelA` is filled in by a ModelForm and then redirect to the form for `ModelB`.
How can I Autofill the `OneToOneField` based on the previous form.
Thank you for helping.

---

I am doing it like this now

```
class ModelBView(CreateView):
.......
    def form_valid(self, form):
        model_b = form.save(commit=False)
        model_a_form = ModelAForm(self.request.POST)
        model_b.model = model_a_form.save(commit=False)
        model_b.save()
        return super(ModelBView, self).form_valid(form)
```

but get the error: "...could not be created because the data didn't validate."

So here the problem is, I simply can get the data from the previous form by request.POST.
How can I get this data.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can save the data from ModelForm for ModelA in request.session or request.get and redirect to the next page for ModelB, where you can get the data for model field in ModelB then fill it.

Comment: thx for the fast answer. i am new to django. how can i save the data?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want exactly.

If you want to auto-fill the field in the second form, then you can use the `initial` keyword argument when instantiating the form for ModelB (e.g. in your view); like this:

```
def my_view(request):
    """
    Save data to ModelA and show the user the form for ModelB
    """
    if request.method == 'POST':
       # Save ModelA instance
       model_a_form = ModelFormA(request.POST)
       if model_a_form.is_valid():
           model_a_instance = model_a_form.save()

           # Once saved, show the user the form for ModelB, prefilled
           # with the result from the previous form
           model_b_form = ModelFormB(initial={'model': model_a_instance})

           # etc. Render the page as usual
       else:
           # ...
   elif request.method == 'GET':
       # ...
```

If, on the other hand, you don't want ModelA to appear in the second form as a field, but still link it to the resulting instance, you can do something like this when handling the response of the second form.

```
# ... instance of first model is saved in `model_a_instance`

# Initiate an empty instance of ModelB, with the value of `model` field set to model_a_instance
model_b_instance = ModelB(model=model_a_instance)

# Provide it as an instance to your model form
model_b_form = ModelFormB(request.POST, instance=model_b_instance)

if model_b_form.is_valid():
     # Everything else should work fine.
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thx. I want to do the second. This is helping very much. But how can i do this in a CreateView class?

Comment: You'll have to override the view's `get()` and `post()` methods and add that logic in it.

Comment: I tried this to, but I get the error "...could not be created because the data didn't validate".

Comment: I think the problem ist. With request.POSt, I get only the data from the current form. But not from the previous form

Comment: i think i got it. i can get the postdata in get_initial